# Generate Mail Merge documents programatically on Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any way to generate a mail merge document programatically via the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013?

Trying to generate a mail merge document via a custom plugin in the back end.

The merged document would then be sent to sharepoint.

But... can't find a "Create Merged Document" feature in the CRM SDK, anyone know of a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done with Mail Merge documents insofar as the way they work with out of the box Dynamics CRM - you need MS Word installed on the client in order to do this, so no API. However, you can still meet the requirement by doing one of the following :

- Write a workflow that retrieves a report, converts it to a document and attaches it to sharepoint like [this](http://mscrmmindfire.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/custom-workflow-to-send-email-with-pdf-formatted-report-as-attachment/)
- Use a third party add-on [Documents Core Pack from MSCRM Addons](http://www.mscrm-addons.com/Products/MSCRM2013/DocumentsCorePack.aspx). The 2013 version provides you with an automerge workflow activity that will auto generate the document and store it in the SharePoint library you have pre-configured for that entity. Note: Templates are created not in the traditional CRM way, but rather by using a MS Word plugin (which gives you more flexibility than Dynamics normal mail merge functionality).
- There is another product called [Xperido](http://www.xperido.com/products/xperido-microsoft-dynamics-crm) that looks like it will do the same thing, but I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks! The add-on looks good, hope they fix the online demo :) Will give the trial a go, this looks like the ticket.