# ms crm 365 / fill word template with data and create word document programmatically c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, word-template, document-template

dcrm 365 has a feature to create word documents using word templates. I want to use this feature in c#,
for example, I have my Invoice entity and the documenttemplate entity. I want to create the result Word document.
is this something that ms crm should handle, eg with a service request or so, or should I do it with a third part library or ...

any direction would be helpful

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546926/generate-mail-merge-documents-programatically-on-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013) seems similar question which is already marked as answered.

Comment: These are different features of dcrm, my question is about Document Template, while your link is about Mail Merge Feature

Answer (score 0):

`SetWordTemplate` is the message which generates a word document based on the provided template and attaches the generated document to the `Note` regarding the `Target` entity.

```
OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest("SetWordTemplate");

req["Target"] = new EntityReference("theEntity", theGuid);
req["SelectedTemplate"] = new EntityReference("documenttemplate", templateGuid);

service.ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest(req);
```

The hassle is, since the document will be attached to a Note you have to recover it with a separate `Retrieve`.

The exact same is available as an Action in a Workflow, add step `Execute Action` > `SetWordTemplate` (not 100% sure about the exact wording, it eludes me atm). Same as above, it creates a Note.

Comment: As you say this attaches it to the Target, however I'm trying to attach it to my own entity

Comment: do you know any third party library to maybe using the template itself and the entity data I can generate the document by my own ?